# Is there a way to reflect changes in MarkerClusters of individual markers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I unhide certain markers. They were previously added to MarkerClusterer. Even when I unhide the markers then don't appear initially, but when I zoom out far enough from the MarkerClusterer, they appear.

Answer (score 1):

How do you actually unhide the markers?

If you look at the source code here: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js, MarkerClusterer actually hides the markers by setting their `map` field to null.

So, you can probably unhide a specific marker hidden by MarkerClusterer by setting its `map` field back to your map reference.

Comment: Yes, I have done what you describe and it does show (unhide) the marker. But you have to be _very_ careful with this, because you are reaching in and interfering with something that the `MarkerClusterer` is supposed to be managing. I only use this very sparingly.